# summing values from one table into another table

Tags: vb6, ms-access-2000

I'm an SQL newbie using VB6/Access 2000 and am trying to get a query which puts the sum of values from a table into another table.
VB6 does the job, but it's so slow.
I searched and tried in Access many times, just got lost with keywords IN, ON, (INNER) JOIN, each time  getting a different error.

The core code should be as follows:

```
update t1
set t1.value = sum(t2.value)
where
val(t2.code)>89
and
t2.date=t1.date
```

- `t1.date` is a date, no duplicates
- `t2.code` is a variable string like '0081', '090'
- values are single precision

After further searching i found a similar question here ( http://goo.gl/uqlw0U ) and tried that:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.value = 
    (
SELECT 
    SUM(t2.value) 
FROM spese
    WHERE
     t1.date=t2.date
AND
    val(t2.code)>89
    )
```

but Access just says "updatable query needed" -- what does that mean?

Comment: Thanks for editing, I'd written the example code exactly like that but it turned inline when i posted.

Comment: In the absence of a "procedural" stored procedure facility I suspect you're screwed since what you want probably can't be expressed as SQL set-based operations.  So you can do this in client code iterating over the updated table with resutls from an aggregate query or you might do this with a JOIN and a make-table query that builds a new table (then DROP the old table, rename the new table via ADOX, create any required indexes).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE t1
 SET t1.value = SUM(t2.value)
FROM t1, t2
WHERE
 val(t2.code)>89
AND
 t2.date=t1.date
```